# How do I prevent myself from ever being tagged in a Facebook post?

Tags: facebook

I don't want anyone to be able to tag me in posts.

It is quite an issue for me, as I am in animal rescue and people think I'll travel out of state to get dogs.

Comment: Hi Tina, we're an independent website not affiliated with Facebook in any way.  This was a bit of a rant, which isn't really helpful to anyone in the future, so I've molded it into a more constructive question that you can likely get an answer to.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to stop getting tagged yourself. Anyone can tag you in photos and other posts. But you can review the tag before they appear on your timeline.

> When a friend tags you in a post on Facebook, normally it automatically appears on your timeline. If someone you're not friends with tags you in a post, you'll be prompted to review it to appear on your timeline. [Timeline Review](https://www.facebook.com/help/168229546579373?helpref=faq_content) lets you require all posts, including friends' posts, to be reviewed before appearing on your timeline.
>
> To turn on Timeline Review or review your Timeline Review settings:
>
> 1. Click *down arrow icon* at the top right of **Facebook** and select **Settings**.
> 2. In the left column, click **Timeline and Tagging**.
> 3. Look for the setting **Review posts you're tagged in before the post appears on your timeline?** and click **Edit** to the far right.
> 4. Select **Enabled** or **Disabled**.

See this to know [How do I control who sees posts and photos that I’m tagged in on my timeline?](https://www.facebook.com/help/267508226592992?helpref=faq_content)

learn more about [**Tagging**](https://www.facebook.com/help/366702950069221).